# Overleaf LaTex file not found error

Tags: graphics, overleaf

I'm having issues with Overleaf, the online LaTeX. I'm trying to include a figure like shown. It keeps saying the file can't be found. However, the p=figure is actually being shown on the pdf but with the title on it twice. There's an error somewhere. It does it normally with my other figures but just this one off the internet. I can't find a url for the picture so can't use alternative methods. Please can someone help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{stars convection.png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try a file name without spaces: `stars-convection.png`.

Comment: You loaded both `graphics` and `graphicx`: only one of them is needed.

Comment: Check also that your file name and extensions have the right case, e.g. if you uploaded `stars-convection.PNG` but you wrote `\includegraphics{stars-convection.png`, then the compiler would not find it.

Answer (score 3):

Put the name within `"..."` with no file extension.

I tried this (of course, renaming and using a .png of mine, since I don't have yours) and it worked:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{"stars convection"}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[Here the result on Overleaf](https://v2.overleaf.com/read/ybbykwsfvjbx).

Also `\includegraphics{"stars convection".png}` works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{"stars convection".png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[Here the result on Overleaf](https://v2.overleaf.com/read/sfmpqdwwntxx).

And remember to load only `graphicx`, without `graphics`.